# Understanding my Deadlock Example of Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I was trying to implement deadlock in java myself.Both the threads t1 and t2 lock on s1 and s2 in same order causing a deadlock situation.However,if I comment out Line1 and Line2 calling sleep method of thread class,deadlock does not occur.I ran this program more than 15 times but removing line 1 and line 2 does not cause deadlock.

So my query is,does line 1 and line2(calling Thread.sleep ) is necessary for deadlock.If yes,then I have not understood deadlock.If no,will it cause deadlock on some other JVM?

```
//Thread DeadLock

class Threadlock 
{
 private final static  String s1="java";
 private final  static String s2="deadlock";
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {  
  Thread t1= new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
      synchronized(s1)
      {
       try { Thread.sleep(100);} 
       catch (Exception e) {}  //Line 1
       synchronized(s2)
       {}
      }
     }
  };

  Thread t2= new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
      synchronized(s2)
      {
        try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}  //Line 2
        synchronized(s1)
        {}
      }
     }
  };

  t2.start();
  t1.start();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Deadlock can occur when some threads needs the same lock at the same time. In your case, as answers says, synchronized blocks do nothing - they need close to "no time" for this. Read http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/deadlock.html , it could help you to understand mechanism better.

Comment: If you comment Line 1 & 2, run your program continuously with the help of other program, I am sure you will understood deadlock by eod.

Comment: One note thought: you want others to spent their time to help you; so you please spend the 1 minute it takes to always format/indet all of your input correctly. But still upvoted ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your methods don't do anything if you remove the sleep. So they are so fast that the probability of the two threads entering their first synchronized block at the same time is very very low. It can still happen, though.

Answer (score 1):

The point is: you have not much control about the underlying implementation. Meaning: although you create two threads and start them "in sequence"; it could very well happen that the JVM/OS in reality ... start t1; runs it; and then afterwards starts t2.

In order to increase your chance of running into a dead-lock; keep your methods doing things at least for several seconds!

In other words: "running into a deadlock" is a function that depends on the actual runtime of your methods *and* details of the underlying implementation.

Comment: Upps. Correct. It isn't a dead lock if the first one gets into the critical section and stays there; and the other doesn't get there. Well, some other sort of dead lock. Anyway; I removed that part. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent programs are inherently undeterministic. In practice potential deadlock may or may not be observed when you execute a faulty program. The code you presented is ill-formed with and without calls to Thread.sleep. The sleeps just seem to make deadlock more evident in your case, but it's there whether you wait for some time or not.